# In Grails 2, how do you includeTargets from Gant scripts from a plugin your app is dependent upon?

Tags: grails, plugins, gant

In Grails 2, I am creating a company specific authentication plugin that depends on the shiro plugin. I would like to reuse shiro's gant scripts in my plugin's gant scripts. My challenge is that I do not know how to access shiro's gant scripts in my includeTargets.

I would like to reuse targets defined in _ShiroInternal.groovy but I do not know what Grails variable to use to access it:

```
includeTargets << new File ("${**what-goes-here**}/scripts/_ShiroInternal.groovy")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property added for each installed plugin, `fooPluginDir`. So for the shiro plugin it would be

```
includeTargets << new File(shiroPluginDir, 'scripts/_ShiroInternal.groovy')
```