# Creating and installing a grails plugin - how does my plugin access resources from a plugin its dependent upon during/after install?

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

This question is an extension from another question I posted here:

[In Grails 2, how do you includeTargets from Gant scripts from a plugin your app is dependent upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253070/in-grails-2-how-do-you-includetargets-from-gant-scripts-from-a-plugin-your-app/15253738?noredirect=1#15253738)

I am writing a grails plugin that is a my-company specific version of the shiro plugin, ex. my-company-shiro. I set shiro as a dependency for my plugin in the BuildConfig.groovy like so:

```
plugins {compile(":shiro:1.1.4")}
```

I package the plugin and try to install it to a new grails app called foo:

```
foo> grails install-plugin ../my-company-shiro/grails-my-company-shiro-01.zip
```

No problems. 
Now, I want to run a script in foo that is part of my-company-shiro which in turn references a script from the shiro plugin:

```
foo>grails create-auth-controller
```

I get the following failure:

```
Error Error executing script CreateAuthController: No such property: shiroPluginDir for class: .....
```

This occurrs b/c one of my scripts being executed tries to access one of shiro's scripts like so:

```
includeTargets << new File (shiroPluginDir, "/scripts/_ShiroInternal.groovy")
```

This reference works when I compile my plugin, but not here when I am installing it in another grails app.

Am I setting the dependency incorrectly in the BuildConfig.groovy such that shiro's files are not being included in my plugin therefor I cannot reference it?

- The shiro plugin shows up in my .grails cache my-compnay-shiro/plugins/shiro-1.1.4
- When I install my-company-shiro plugin to foo, in the .grails cache foo/plugins/my-company-shiro-0.1/dependencies.groovy and plugin.xml files reference shiro. I do not see any of shiro's scripts or files here, but I have no idea if they are supposed to be copied here.

Is the reference to shiroPlugin incorrect at install time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But the error says that there is no such property: shiroPluginDir. I am confused :S

Comment: The shiroPluginDir property is visible when I package my plugin b/c I have shiro set as a plugin dependency. When I install my plugin to a project, I am assuming that the shiro plugin gets installed as well and this property would be visible by default (ala the answer to referenced question).

Comment: As a note, when I list-plugins on the app I installed my plugin on, my-company-shiro is listed, but shiro is not. So, if shiro is not installed, I probably will not be able to reference the default <plugin-name>PluginDir. So how can I access the shiro scripts at this time?

Comment: Please post your script that have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grails install-plugin` is deprecated, you need to use `BuildConfig.groovy` instead. I tested here, declaring the custom plugin inside the app and it works, you can use `grails.plugin.location` to specify the folder of your plugin.

Considering a plugin named **shiro-test**, the BuildConfig should be:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   ...
   legacyResolve true // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
   ...
}

grails.plugin.location."shiro-test" = "path/to/plugin"
```

Then you refresh your dependencies and can run any script from `shiro-test`.

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Seems obvious now, I just did not figure that a compile cycle was needed when updating the BuildConfig.groovy.